# Block tables in Summernote WYSIWYG editer

Tags: bootstrap-4, summernote

Does anyone know if it is possible to only have text formatting and completely disable tables pasted into the editor textarea.

I know how to only display the font styling toolbar, but how do i disable tables completely?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('textarea#summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onPaste: function(e) {
      const html = (e.originalEvent.clipboardData).getData('text/html');
      const tagName = $(html)[0]?.tagName;
      if (tagName === 'TABLE') {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  },
  placeholder: 'Hello bootstrap 4',
  tabsize: 2,
  height: 100,
  toolbar: [
    ['style', ['style']],
    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']],
    ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
    ['help', ['help']]
  ],
});
```